# Introduction movie running before game starts

Tags: unity

There are many games out there that feature a movie or cut scene to feature either in-game features or to set the mood for the player. Some examples are the intro from Tony Hawk Pro Skater 4, Fifa Street 2, Modern Warfare 3, etc. How do I integrate a movie I made to Unity so it launches right at the start, ends playing and then shows the main menu? Is it available for unity personal edition or is it only for pro users?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The component you are looking for is the [MovieTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html).

- Create a scene "intro" with a *UI->Canvas*.
- Add a *UI->Raw Image* to the canvas
- Import your video as a movie texture and attach it as texture to the image
- Enlarge the image so it fills the whole screen
- Add a script which plays the movie and then loads your main menu scene when the video is finished (or the player cancels it).
- Make this scene your start scene

Comment: Note: You may want to add a flag to only show this scene at startup once. It annoys players to have to sit through the same cinematic every time they launch the game.

Comment: Actually I would make it skippable rather than avoid it altogether.  Presuming the same player is playing or that they don't want to see what I'm sure is a magnum opus more than once takes choice away from the player.  You may want to incorporate the older arcade technique of showing the "attract mode" movie after the main menu rather than before to help mitigate the irritation factor.  And obviously if they're continuing a saved game (if that's applicable), you wouldn't want to show it again.  Common sense stuff, really.

Comment: Both of your comments can be merged together, now that I think of it. The options should feature a "Enable/Disable introduction movie" and the game at the start should have a text in a visible area that reads: "Press enter/any key to continue". I didn't think about this when until you guys said so. Thanks for the comments I will surely apply this to my game. Happy Holidays.